# Mysql Select Multiple Table Get Value with same Column

Tags: php, mysql

Okay that was harsh,

Anyways, I revised my question and made an example of code here.

What I wanted to do is, I **need** to get the **giveaway table's column title value** and **competition column title value**

```
$query = "SELECT giveaway_table.title, competition.title FROM giveaway_table, competition WHERE giveaway_table.status=competition.status";
$result = db_query($query)->fetchObject();
```

How do I retrieve the value?

When I used this

```
echo $result->title;
```

it only echo the competition's title value.

**How do I retrieve the giveaway table's title column value?**

I used this

```
$result->title[0]
```

it only shows the First letter of the Title of Competition's title value.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use different alias:

```
$query = "SELECT giveaway_table.title as gtitle, competition.title as ctitle FROM giveaway_table, competition WHERE giveaway_table.status=competition.status";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use aliases to clear up the ambiguity:

```
$query = "SELECT giveaway_table.title AS giveaway_title, competition.title AS competition_title FROM giveaway_table, competition WHERE giveaway_table.status=competition.status";
$result = db_query($query)->fetchObject();
```

Then echo:

```
echo $result->competition_title;
echo $result->giveaway_title;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use aliases

```
SELECT
  giveaway_table.title AS GiveAwayTitle,
  competition.title AS CompetitionTitle
FROM giveaway_table,
  competition
WHERE giveaway_table.status = competition.status
```

With php

```
echo $result->GiveAwayTitle;
echo $result->CompetitionTitle;
```